# React: Detect a variable's PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

In a React component, if I declare:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  // An object that could be one of many types
  header: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number,
  ]),
}
```

How do I know if `header` is a string or a number in my `render` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if the value's type is one of primitive types (string, number ...), you can use the above approach of @jrubins.

For self-defined React components, you must check the associated field `.type`. Here is the demo code:

```
Steps.propTypes = {
  // must not be an empty array of Step
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(function(props, propName) {
    const value = props[propName];
    if ( value.type !== Step) {
      return new Error('Must supply an instance of Step');
    }
  }),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `render` method, you could use the `typeof` operator to determine the type of the `header` variable. If you have something like Lodash, you could use one of its utility methods as well ([_.isString](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isString), [_.isNumber](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNumber), etc.).

Note: Your comment "An object that could be one..." should probably be restated as "A **variable** that could be one..." since you're saying that it's not an object but rather either a string or a number.